# cache optimization of matrice operation

Tags: c++, matrix, cpu-cache

As a precomputation to a integral function, I need make some computation on a large matrice.

```
for (size_t x = 1; x < size().x(); ++x)
for (size_t y = 0; y < size().y(); ++y)
for (size_t z = 0; z < size().z(); ++z)
    field::at(x, y, z) += field::at(x - 1, y, z);

for (size_t x = 0; x < size().x(); ++x)
for (size_t y = 1; y < size().y(); ++y)
for (size_t z = 0; z < size().z(); ++z)
    field::at(x, y, z) += field::at(x, y - 1, z);

for (size_t x = 0; x < size().x(); ++x)
for (size_t y = 0; y < size().y(); ++y)
for (size_t z = 1; z < size().z(); ++z)
    field::at(x, y, z) += field::at(x, y, z - 1);
```

my field inherit a `std::vector<size_t>` where the `at` as been overided

```
T& at(size_t x, size_t y, size_t z)
{
    return container::at(x + y * size().x() + z * size().x() * size().y();
}
```

Here are some execution times on my machine

- (128x128x128) ~ 250 ms
- (256x256x256) ~ 3 sec
- (512x512x512) ~ 53 sec

That looks very slow to me.

### Question

- Is allocating a `std::vector` of size 512x512x512 (1G) a bad idea ? Should I divide it in multiple (512) sub vector of size 512x512 (2M/each)
- Is there any other way to do the same simple computation which would be more cache efficient ? (I'm guessing cache faults are a reason why this is so slow)

Comment: Try to change the access pattern, invert the for loops, first `z`, then `y`, later `x`, in this form the inner loop would be with `x` and the custom `at` would be accessing **continuous memory** (cache friendly).

Comment: Thank you, that helped a LOT ! 512x512x512 reduced from 53s to 3s